# How to order records by their latest child records attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many, has-one

I'm having troubles to order my records by their has_one association. I'm quite sure the solution is obvious, but I just can't get it.

```
class Migration
  has_many :checks
  has_one :latest_origin_check, -> { where(origin: true).order(at: :desc) }, class_name: 'Check'
end

class Check
  belongs_to :migration
end
```

If I order by checks.status I always get different check ids. Shouldn't they be the same but with different order?

Or is the -> { } way to get the has_one association the problem?

```
Migration.all.includes(:latest_origin_check).order("checks.status DESC").each do |m| puts m.latest_origin_check.id end
```

So in one sentence: How do I order records through a custom has_one association?

I'm using Ruby 2.0.0, Rails 4.2 and PostgreSQL.

**Update:**

I wasn't specific enough. I've got two has_one relations on the checks relation. 
Also very Important. One Migration has a way to big number of checks to include all the checks at once. So Migration.first.includes(:checks) would be very slow. We are talking about serveral thousand and I only need the latest.

```
class Migration
  has_many :checks
  has_one :latest_origin_check, -> { where(origin: true).order(at: :desc) }, class_name: 'Check'
  has_one :latest_target_check, -> { where(origin: false).order(at: :desc) }, class_name: 'Check'


end

class Check
  belongs_to :migration
end
```

Now if I get the latest_origin_check, I get the correct Record. The query is the following.

```
pry(main)> Migration.last.latest_origin_check
Migration Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "migrations".* FROM "migrations"  ORDER BY  "migrations"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
Check Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "checks".* FROM "checks" WHERE "checks"."migration_id" = $1 AND "checks"."origin" = 't'  ORDER BY "checks"."at" DESC LIMIT 1  [["migration_id", 59]]
```

**How do I get the latest check of each migration and then sort the migrations by a attribute of the latest check?**

I'm using ransack. Ransack seems to get it right when I order the records by "checks.at"

```
SELECT "migrations".* FROM "migrations" LEFT OUTER JOIN "checks" ON "checks"."migration_id" = "migrations"."id" AND "checks"."origin" = 't' WHERE (beginning between '2015-02-22 23:00:00.000000' and '2015-02-23 22:59:59.000000' or ending between '2015-02-22 23:00:00.000000' and '2015-02-23 22:59:59.000000') ORDER BY "checks"."at" ASC
```

But the same query returns wrong results when I order by status

```
SELECT "migrations".* FROM "migrations" LEFT OUTER JOIN "checks" ON "checks"."migration_id" = "migrations"."id" AND "checks"."origin" = 't' WHERE (beginning between '2015-02-22 23:00:00.000000' and '2015-02-23 22:59:59.000000' or ending between '2015-02-22 23:00:00.000000' and '2015-02-23 22:59:59.000000') ORDER BY "checks"."status" ASC
```

Check.status is a boolean, check.at is a DateTime. A colleague suggested that the boolean is the problem. Do I need to convert the booleans to an integer to make them sortable? How do I do that only for the :latest_origin_check? Something like that?

```
.order("(case when \"checks\".\"status\" then 2 when \"checks\".\"status\" is null  then 0 else 1 end) DESC")
```

Comment: First, did you mean `where(origin: true).order(status: :desc)`? Second, the way you have the lambda looks like it should work. When you run `migration.latest_origin_check` in the console, what does the SQL look like? Could you include that?

Comment: @evanbikes you were right. My question was not specific enough and there were some details missing. I added some more details in the update. The situation is actually even more difficult. :-(

Answer (score 0):

You already have a has_many relationship with `Check` on `Migration`.  I think you are looking for a scope instead:

```
scope :latest_origin_check, -> { includes(:checks).where(origin:true).order("checks.status DESC").limit(1)}
```

Drop the `has_one :latest_origin_check` line on `Migration`.

```
Migration.latest_origin_check
```

I think the line about should return your desired result set.